# data from python showing in one column instead of two on ppostgresqll

Tags: python, sql, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

The tables are showing but all the data is showing under HY. I want row 19 to show under HY and row 20 to show under AY. For a fact, AY column is getting created but all lines say [null]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys
import csv
from itertools import count
path = r'C:\Users\sammy\Downloads\E0.csv'
with open(path, "r") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    firstline = 1
    con = None
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='football' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE testtest1234")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE testtest1234 (HY INTEGER, AY INTEGER)")

try:
    for row in readCSV:
        if firstline:
            firstline=0
            continue 
        new_data = row[19]
        newer_data = row[20]
        print(new_data)
        print(newer_data)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest1234 values ("+new_data+"), ("+newer_data+")")
except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    if con:
        con.rollback() 
        print ("Error %s % e", e)
        sys.exit(1) 
finally:
    if con:
        con.commit()
        con.close()

print(" ".join(row))
out=open("new_data.csv", "w")
output = csv.writer(out)

for row in new_data:
    output.writerow(row)

out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have formed the query looks wrong to me, here's how you can make it work.

create a tuple of data to be inserted into table:

```
data = (new_data, newer_data)
```

Then create query statement as:

```
query =  "INSERT INTO items (HY, AY) VALUES (%s, %s);"
```

Then you can execute the query as:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Then commit it:

```
conn.commit()
```

Your Edited code here:

```
for row in readCSV:
    if firstline:
        firstline=0
        continue
    new_data = row[19]
    newer_data = row[20]
    data = (new_data, newer_data)
    query = "INSERT INTO testtest1234 (HY, AY) VALUES (%s, %s);"
    print(new_data)
    print(newer_data)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unsure about where exactly to add these, could you please copy paste the code and edit the relevant parts? Many thanks!

Comment: It should go inside your try block, replace the last line with these 4 lines, it should work.

Comment: I am dealing with another issue. At L28:
" cur.execute("INSERT INTO testtest1234 values (%s, %s)", ("+new_data+", "+newer_data+")
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        if con:"

 except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Weird one..

Comment: Error %s % e relation "items" does not exist

We're getting there slowly :)

Comment: Is the data you are trying to insert is integer?

Comment: It worked! Had to change "items" to table name.. Many thanks man!

Comment: And yes it is integers, at least for now :)

Comment: I need your help with another question concerning that code.. Should I post a new question in two hours (i don't have access to chat yet) or reach out to you on twitter?

Comment: If this answer worked for you, can you accept it as the right answer? Regarding another issue, you can ask the question by posting a new question.

Comment: Will have to wait 1.5 hrs to ask another question :p
How do I accept it as correct answer? I put a thumbs up